# Crystal Report 7 Merge Module

Tags: crystal-reports

Does anyone know the Crystal Reports 7 Merge Module download page?

I'm re-composing a installer of legacy program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crikey, I doubt very much that you'll find the modules for CR7 at this stage. It's got to be at least 10 to 12 years old. If you have a machine that your legacy application is installed on then your best bet is to use a dependency walker to figure out which components are needed to provide run  time support for it. CR7 wasn't as difficult to install the runtime for as some of the more recent versions and  there’s only a handful of files you’ll need to get copies of. A good start point would be to check the properties of the files in the System32 directory that start with "CR" (E.g. CRPE32.dll & CRRUN32.exe) and work forward from there.

Comment: thanks. I've found several dlls inside the legacy installation file.